# how to add in app purchase in my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to use in app purchase application in my application but i have no more knowledge how to do this.
    any body help me how to do and where is source code is available. give me link or code.

Comment: You've asked many questions & accepted none of the answers; there's little incentive for anyone to answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a bunch of links:

- [In App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [StoreKit framework reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKit_Collection/index.html)
- [UrbanAirship.com](http://urbanairship.com) (A site that offers a more convenient API than StoreKit)
- [The One Resource](http://tinyurl.com/ycr5h8o)

Answer (score 4):

There is the full set of articles how to do it with good explanation. This should be good for starting:

- [All About In-App Purchases Part 1: Displaying Store Items](http://gamesfromwithin.com/in-app-purchases-part-1)
- [All About In-App Purchases Part 2: Selling The Goods](http://gamesfromwithin.com/in-app-purchases-part-2)
- [All About In-App Purchases Part 3: Anti-Piracy Measures](http://gamesfromwithin.com/in-app-purchases-part-3)
- [All About In-App Purchases Part 4: iTunes Connect](http://gamesfromwithin.com/in-app-purchases-part-4)

Answer (score 1):

I found this interesting article giving 5 tips if you want to [add in-app purchase](http://soom.la/add-in-app-purchase/)

- TIP 1 - Let the user win coins
- TIP 2 - Give the user Bonus Coins
- TIP 3 - Make Every Purchase a Reason to Purchase More
- TIP 4 - Implement at least two currencies
- TIP 5 - Make an Evolving Store