# Iphone development

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone .How can i develop appstore using store kit .can any one explain the necessary steps ..Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/howto-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c and / or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115358/how-to-add-in-app-purchase-in-my-application

Answer (score 4):

1) **You need a mac.** If your on a budget get a macbook or mac mini.

2) **Get the developer tools with the iphone SDK.** This will give you GCC and all of the basic tools required. Its free but you do have to register at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/tools/) . You can pay the $99 later on when you actually are ready to sell an app in the app store.

3) **You need to know objective C**. If have C experience you can pick up objective C pretty fast. I recommend ["Programming in Objective-C" by Kochan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321566157)

4) **Learn Cocoa.** The book that really opened my eyes to this was ["Cocoa Programming for Mac OSX"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619) by Aaron Hillegass. Any of the Aaron Hillegass books are great. I think he has some specific stuff to the iphone now as well.

5) **Learn Cocoa Touch**. I would use the online documentation. Its gotten me pretty far.

At this point your off to a good start. I highly recommend reading the apple documentation and using google. If you like to learn by looking at working code, Apple also has allot of ready made simple apps. There is allot of information out there for people willing to look it up. Don't be afraid to ask questions here but be specific and provide lots of details. No one started out knowing everything. I wish you happy learning and good luck.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get a Mac
2. Join the [developer program](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/), [download tools](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/). Learn [cocoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_Touch), [Objective C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C)
3. Develop
4. Send application to Apple for approval

[MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) allows you to use C# (or another .NET language) instead of Objective-C.

Comment: you forgot the 'profit!' step!

Answer (score 0):

Learn Objective-C whilst creating Cocoa apps. Once you understand, learn the iPhone APIs and start to create iPhone apps