# How to implement In App Purchasing from my iphone/ipad application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

How to implement In App Purchasing from my iphone/ipad application. I just want to show my applications which are in the AppStore so customer can easily buy the application from my application.?

Help me out thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For implementing In-App Purchase, check out [Adding In-App Purchase to your Apps](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/inapppurchase/) and the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

I don't think, however, Apple will accept In-App Purchases for your desired use - you'd probably be better off with a page that lists your apps, with links to the respective App Store pages.

Comment: Thank you i will go through it soon..and i will update you it is helpful or not for me. Thank you.

Comment: I am not able to implement using this because I am totally confused where i have to implement what? Please help me out THanks

Comment: While I still don't think you should be using in-app purchase for this, this has been asked before, these questions should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115358/how-to-add-in-app-purchase-in-my-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931546/how-to-add-in-app-purchase-code-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add in app purchase to do this.. actually you can't do this with in app purchase.. you need to create a xml file in which you have to list your apps then you can parse this xml file in your app and you can create links to your using this -

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/in/app/angry-birds/id343200656?mt=8"]];
```

this will open the default app store app on iphone or ipad